# Splitting a table up into sections?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table, material-ui

I'm currently using Material UI for a personal project, but I suppose this is a more general question about tables.  I have a figma layout I made that I think looks nice, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it.

[image: Here is the Figma design]

Currently I have a MUI table, but there's two issues.  **One**, I don't know how to make the very top 3 headers a part of the table, I can manually position them but if you resize a screen they will move out of position from the table contents.  **Two**, how the heck can I section a table like this?   To have the table headers justified left in sections?

It's been a frustrating day to work on this, while I was designing this felt like a normal table design, but I can't figure out how the heck to section into three parts.

[image: What my current table looks like]

Here is my current code:

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
    return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
    createData("Frozen yoghurt", 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
    createData("Ice cream sandwich", 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
    createData("Eclair", 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
    createData("Cupcake", 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
    createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
];

const StyledTableRow = styled(TableRow)(({ theme }) => ({
    "&:nth-of-type(odd)": {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
    },
    // hide last border
    "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": {
        border: 0,
    },
}));

export default function DenseTable() {
    return (
        <Box sx={{ mt: 3 }}>
            <Grid container>
                <Grid item xs>
                    <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 16 }} component="h2">
                        <b>Header 1</b>
                    </Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs>
                    <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 16 }} component="h2">
                        <b>header 2</b>
                    </Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs>
                    <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 16 }} component="h2">
                        <b>Header 3</b>
                    </Typography>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            {/*  */}
            <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} size="small" aria-label="a dense table">
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>header 1</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>header 2</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>header 3 </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>header 4</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>header 5</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                        {rows.map((row) => (
                            <StyledTableRow
                                key={row.name}
                                sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
                            >
                                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                    {row.name}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
                            </StyledTableRow>
                        ))}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
        </Box>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For problem **One**, you don't need to create headers outside of a the table itself -- you can just add another `TableRow`.  Additionally, a `TableCell` accepts the property `colspan` which allows you to define the number of columns you would like each cell to occupy.

```
<TableCell colspan={5}>
  ...
</TableCell>
```

For problem **Two**, that's just a styling issue and you can "section" the table by defining the `borderRight` for the cell that you'd like to denote as the end of a "section".

I prepared a *quick and dirty* example using your code and your figma layout.  You'll want to clean this up quite a bit, but this should set you in the right direction.

[image]

That was a fun problem!

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sectioned-table-with-top-header-63qb4?file=/demo.js

Comment: I didn't tackle the bottom border of the table itself as it seemed outside of scope for your original question, but that should be an easy enough fix.